# My main class doesn't seem to add a object

Tags: java, swing

I'm kind of new-ish to Java.

I'm currently trying to add a footer JPanel to my Swing app. I'm doing this by having the JPanel for the footer in a separate class.

This is my FooterBar-class that has the JPanel properties in it:

```
public class FooterBar extends JPanel {

    private JPanel footerPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label;

    public FooterBar() {

        // Footer test
        footerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 16));
        footerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(footerPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        footerPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        JLabel label;

        label = new JLabel("test");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        footerPanel.add(label);

        label = new JLabel("test 2");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        footerPanel.add(label);

    }

}
```

And this is what I have in my main class. (Called MainFrame)

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private TextPanel textPanel = new TextPanel();
    private Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
    private FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
    private FooterBar footerPanel = new FooterBar();

private static String windowTitle = "WIN7 USB3 Installer";

/**
 * The properties for the window itself
 */
public MainFrame() {
    super(windowTitle);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    add(formPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(footerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

}

If I had all the JPanel properties inside my main class, it works perfectly. But it doesn't show the JPanel with 2 different classes.
Though the other components does move up a bit, so they won't collide with the JPanel. So I guess it just doesn't initialize the actual JPanel. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FooterBar` is already a `JPanel`, creating another `JPanel` and adding things to it has no use, so just use your `FooterBar` panel directly  :

```
public class FooterBar extends JPanel {

    private JLabel label;

    public FooterBar() {

        // Footer test
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), 16));
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        JLabel label;

        label = new JLabel("test");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        add(label);

        label = new JLabel("test 2");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(label);

    }

}
```

Comment: Like most of the times, I manage to realize what I did wrong right after asking, haha! Thanks for the reply, confirming this is the correct way :)

Comment: @Condolent sounds like you need to buy [a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)